# variable in an a sql query in a vba module

Tags: sql, vba, variables

I am trying to pass the value of a variable to an UPDATE sql query in vba module for ACCESS.

```
Dim x As Long
x = DSum("[column1]", "table1")
DoCmd.RunSQL " UPDATE table1 SET column2 = x"
```

Instead of passing the assigned value of x to column2 prompts the parameter pop up window asking for a value. Any suggestions and/or corrections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to exclude `x` from quotation:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL " UPDATE table1 SET column2 = " & x
```

If it is included within quotation, the compiler uses letter *x* simply (instead of the value assigned to variable `x`).

If it is excluded from quotation and appended with ampersand, compiler knows that you mean to use the value assigned to variable `x`.

Comment: brilliant! Thank you mate!